# How to say "find a way to do something" better, in English?

Tags: meaning

For example, I want to do something, but I don't know how to do it even I had tried.

A real example, I'm using an open-source library, and I want to add some of my own functions:

> I may want to add a until() and trimLeft(..) and trimRight(...), that I can write it as:
>
> string("/*").trimLeft().until(string("*/"))
>
> But I don't find a way to do it.

Here I'm using "find a way", but I don't know if it's good. Or "find a solution"? Or "find a method"? Or some other words?

In other case, e.g. I don't know how to open a box, is there any other way(right?) to express "I don't know how to do it"?

There may be a lot of mistakes in this question, I'll be very appreciate if you can point them out.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful. ¶ For the current question, consider “I don't see how to do it”, “I haven't figured out how”, and “It isn't clear what to do”

Comment: This is a programming naming question, which is expressly forbidden in the FAQ.

Comment: @Robusto It's not a programming question. The real-word application is his attempting describing his making an effort to achieve an end; That that end is related to programming is incidental.

Comment: *Find a way* (meaning *identify a means of doing this*) is fine. The interesting part of your question, which you may want to edit to focus on, is why English does not use *I don't **find*** but can use *I don't **know***.

Comment: In your example, you should use "I can't find a way to do it" rather than "I don't ...". But there is nothing wrong with "find a way to do it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sounds wrong, but the problem isn't with "find a way", it's with "don't". That suggests that not finding a way to do it is a habitual thing. Replace it with "can't". "But I can't find a way to do it." Perfectly idiomatic, and seems to express what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**[solution](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/solution)** *noun*
**1a** means of solving a problem or dealing with a difficult situation

The *way* you are looking for is called a *solution* in the context -- "a way to solve".

> But I can't find *the right solution*.